# C# Overwrite file failed badly

Tags: c#, file, overwrite

Tried several times to make this work but with several failures.
let me explain what i've tried to do: 
 1.Unrar the files in zip format (working) 
 2.Unraring to a named directory (unrars) 
 3.Copying from unrars folder to another folder(not working) 
 So my question is : Did i used a correct overwrite format? i set the bool overwrite to true.

```
foreach (string fisier in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(fisier, fisier.Replace(TheSourcePath, TheDestinationPath), true);

            }
```

Comment: "Not working" is about as vague as "failed badly".  May we have a more precise clue?

Comment: maybe your application has not enough rights to overwrite the file?

Comment: Not working as : it doesn't overwrite the file(if the file does not exists its copying it without problems,if not overwrite don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an odd way to get the destination path to me, can't you just have it as a string?

It might be that the string replace isn't creating a valid path.

I assume `TheDestinationPath' is a const, in which case is won't have the file name on it, or you'll be copying over a file from the second iteration.

Comment: Yes ur right,i thought about that too,can you provide an exmaple?